# An Embedded the twitter timeline in not working in IBM Client 9.0.0

Tags: twitter, xpages, lotus-notes, xpinc

I used the HTML Code provided by Twitter  (https://publish.twitter.com/).

The given code is like

`<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

this code is embedded in an XPages and the XPages is displayed in XPinc

For some IBM Notes client (seems only the version 9.0.0), the timeline is not loaded.
With the 9.0.1+ version of the IBM Notes client, it works well.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

the pb was not due to the version of the Notes Client.
The Xpages was opened from a local replica.

The proxy congifuration did not allow to open the external websites (plateform.twitter.com) and the localhost (127.0.0.1) used for running the Xpages.

Changing the proxy setting in the location document by setting do not use proxy for localhost ip address solved the pb.